# load hundreds of dataset from Github in R

Tags: r, github

From Johns Hopkins University COVID dataset, the data are in separate pages per date. [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nQAEE.png)

I hope to read all the datasets in R without having to code read.table(url("")) hundred times. After reading them in R, I'm planning on merging them by adding a "date" column. Is there a way to go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be easier ways -- I am pretty sure the JHU data set has aggregations.  Others work off it too, and/or provide other aggregations.

For example, I have been using [this git repo by the New York Times](https://github.com/nytimes/covid-19-data) daily for 14 or so months now. You can just clone it, update daily and enjoy the curated csv files.

Comment: You are welcome, and a belated welcome to StackOverflow too.  It is customary to a) "upvote" (by clicking on the upward triangle) an answer that you think is helpful and/or b) "accept" (by clicking on the tickmark only you as asker see) an answer that solves your question.  You too get karma points for accepting an answer.